# IndexError: tuple index out of range in python by using Raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, syntax-error, weather-api

Here is a code for calculating the radiation of the sun, but when I'm trying to run the code I get this error:

```
   Parsed config:  None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/SolarRadiationPlugin-master/run_plugin.py", line 13, in <module>
    print('Sunrise: {0}\r\nSunset: {1}'.format(solar_radiation.get_sunrise_sunset()))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I'm not sure why this error is showing,

and here is the main code code :

https://github.com/UBayouski/SolarRadiationPlugin

Comment: Please post the relevant code snippet directly in your question as text, instead of a link to an off-site location

Comment: `print('Sunrise: {0}\r\nSunset: {1}'.format(solar_radiation.get_sunrise_sunset()))` you only pass 1 argument to `format` yet you specify `{0}` and {1}` which would require two arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`solar_radiation.get_sunrise_sunset()` returns a tuple of length 2. To use it with string formatting, you can unpack the tuple with `*`.

```
print('Sunrise: {0}\r\nSunset: {1}'.format(*solar_radiation.get_sunrise_sunset()))
```

In my opinion, you can improve readability by defining the values before the print.

```
sunrise, sunset = solar_radiation.get_sunrise_sunset()
print('Sunrise: {0}\r\nSunset: {1}'.format(sunrise, sunset))
```

or with f-strings

```
sunrise, sunset = solar_radiation.get_sunrise_sunset()
print(f'Sunrise: {sunrise}\r\nSunset: {sunset}'
```

Comment: Great, please consider accepting this as the answer by clicking the green checkmark on the left.